# Label Multiple SQL queries

Tags: sql, winsql

I run 12 different queries simultaneously as part of doing some research. I would like to find a way to give a label to title to each query that shows up in WINSql results window...

i.e.

```
 QUERY #1
 RCPT INT#      SEX  NAME
 ---- --------- ---- -------------------------------------- 
 0 Row(s) affected

 QUERY #2
 ORD  COUNTRY   SEX  NAME
 ---- --------- ---- -------------------------------------- 
 0 Row(s) affected
```

etc.

Is there a way to do this? So far I have looked here, on the internet and in WINSql help files and

Comment: Just add a column to the query `Select .... , 'Query#1' as Source...`  it repeats but you know the source of every record that way; and if you union the results it keeps duplicate data from being eliminated from each query (though not within itself for that you'd have to use union all)

Comment: That works, not the format I am looking for but will do in the short term. Thank you .